Fortify enablement on android-gif-drawable library
we are using android-gif-drawable library in our app and have received a PenTest report that FORTIFY is not enabled in the library and reported as a vulnerability. We are currently using version 1.2.19 and it would be of great help if someone could help us determine if FORTIFY has been enabled in any of the recent versions of the library
Need help to know if FORTIFY has been enabled in the recent versions of the library.
